# Use a form in rails but not save the inputs on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, google-drive-api

maybe this will sound a bit weird but what I want to do is store the inputs of a modal form in variables such that those data is not saved on database but in a google-sheet instead. I have already configured succesfully loading data into google-sheets, so that is not a problem but I can not figure how to store the data of that modal form in variables out in the way that I dont have to create new records for that information because I will store it on google-drive instead. Can you suggest any idea to do this please?

Comment: you can easily fetch data like @model.field_name and assign to google-sheet

Comment: Yes but I hace to create the model and its field columns in database in order to use it like that, what I want is not creating a model for it just use some variables because having an space in DB for that information is not longer useful since I am storing it in a google-sheet

Comment: ook, can get values from form like params[:first_value]...params[last_value]